# Django Rest Framework serializer losing data

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

In my unittests, and in reality, the ModelSerializer class I've created just seems to discard a whole trove of data it is provided with:

```
class KeyboardSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.Field(source='user.username')
    mappings = KeyMapSerializer(many=True, source='*')

    class Meta:
        model = Keyboard
        fields = ('user', 'label', 'is_primary', 'created', 'last_modified', 'mappings')

    def pre_save(self, obj):
        obj.user = self.request.user

TEST_KEYBOARD_MAP = {
                        'user': None,
                        'label': 'New',
                        'is_primary': True,
                        'created': '2013-10-22T12:15:05.118Z',
                        'last_modified': '2013-10-22T12:15:05.118Z',
                        'mappings': [
                            {'cellid': 1, 'key': 'q'},
                            {'cellid': 2, 'key': 'w'},
                        ]
}

class SerializerTests(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.data = TEST_KEYBOARD_MAP

    def test_create(self):
        serializer = KeyboardSerializer(data=self.data)
        print serializer.data
```

Output:

```
{'user': u'', 'label': u'', 'is_primary': False, 'created': None, 'last_modified': None, 'mappings': {'id': u'', 'cellid': None, 'key': u''}}
```

What is happening to all the information passed in to the serializer in data?

Comment: Can you post the output too?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `data` key is not populated until you call `is_valid()`. (This is a data-sanitation safety feature that stops you accessing input until you're sure it's safe.

Add the call to `is_valid()` and you should see your data.

Since you're deserializing though you want to access the `object` attribute to return you `Keyboard` instance.

If you review [the DRF docs on deserializing objects](http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers.html#deserializing-objects) they show exactly the example you need:

> ```
> serializer = CommentSerializer(data=data)
> serializer.is_valid()
> # True
> serializer.object
> # <Comment object at 0x10633b2d0>
> ```

I hope that helps.

Comment: Aha, I see. Now just running into issues that despite .is_valid() being true, I can't get the object due to failure in M2M creation/editing - ```ValueError: "<Keyboard: Keyboard  for test5>" needs to have a value for field "keyboard" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.``` - where do I need to override to implement saving of M2M objects

Comment: Ah. Nested Writes. A ticky one. Your best bet (currently) is separate endpoints and a flat representation using HyperlinkedRelatedField. http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations.html — Browsing the DRF tag will give you plenty more if you want extra detail.  (The actual error is caused because you need both sides of the relation set before you save the relation.)

Comment: Hmm ... I've made a solution which works via the save_object() on the parent object's serializer, and creating/updating the relations on the fly after saving the parent. The issue with this is I ideally want to grab the data from ```serializer.data```, but it appears validation just removes the nested sources from the dictionary?

Comment: That'd work. The other idea is do it post_save in the view... — Try making the resource read-only and see if you get the output you're looking for. (You might then be pushed towards the view route) Also check out the `init_data` attribute. Beyond that you just need to find a way that works and run with it — nested writes are a work in progress as of now. (They're non-trivial.)

Comment: Is ```init_data``` covered by the validation? Validation works for the nested data, but then appears to remove it from the ```data``` attribute.

Comment: No — it's just the data you provide. Take a look at the source. You're trying to work round what's built-in — I'd just thought I'd mention it since you mentioned overriding save_object.

Comment: Ah, ok sure. Thanks for the help! Essentially, from my tests (and the source), it does validate the input, just then drops it from ```.data```, worst case scenario, I can just pull it from ```.init_data```, and then use that for the downstream generation of the child objects, which currently fail. Thanks for your help!

Comment: No Problem! Since the answer addresses the question accepting it and/or upvotes would be appreciated ;-)

Comment: Heh, certainly, was just concluding the chat above first ;) Thanks again!